# Improve parsing speed of delimited configuration block

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a quite large configuration file that consists of blocks delimited by

`#start <some-name> ... #end <some-name>` were `some-name` has to be the same for the block. The block can appear multiple times but is never contained within itself. Only some other blocks may appear in certain blocks. I'm not interested in these contained blocks, but on the blocks in the second level.

In the real file the names do not start with `blockX` but are very different from each other.

An example:

```
#start block1

  #start block2

    /* string but no more name2 or name1 in here */
  #end block2

  #start block3
   /* configuration data */
  #end block3

#end block1
```

This is being parsed with regex and is, when run without a debugger attached, quite fast. 0.23s for a <strike>2k</strike> 2.7MB file with simple rules like:

```
blocks2 = re.findAll('#start block2\s+(.*?)#end block2', contents)
```

I tried parsing this with pyparsing but the speed is VERY slow even without a debugger attached, it took 16s for the same file.

My approach was to produce a pyparsing code that would mimic the simple parsing from the regex so I can use some of the other code for now and avoid having to parse every block now. The grammar is quite extense.

Here is what I tried

```
block = [Group(Keyword(x) + SkipTo(Keyword('#end') + Keyword(x)) + Keyword('#end') - x )(x + '*') for x in ['block3', 'block4', 'block5', 'block6', 'block7', 'block8']]

blocks = Keyword('#start') + block

x = OneOrMore(blocks).searchString(contents)  # I also tried parseString() but the results were similar.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I optimize this to come anywhere close to the speed achieved by the regex implementation?

**Edit:** The previous example was way to easy compared to the real data, so i created a proper one now:

```
/* all comments are C comments */
VERSION 1 0
#start PROJECT project_name "what is it about"
    /* why not another comment here too! */
    #start SECTION where_the_wild_things_are "explain this section"


        /* I need all sections at this level */

        /* In the real data there are about 10k of such blocks.
           There are around 10 different names (types) of blocks */


        #start INTERFACE_SPEC
         There can be anything in the section. Not Really but i want to skip anything until the matching (hash)end.
         /* can also have comments */

        #end INTERFACE_SPEC

        #start some_other_section
            name 'section name'

            #start with_inner_section
              number_of_points 3 /* can have comments anywhere */
            #end with_inner_section
        #end some_other_section /* basically comments can be anywhere */

        #start some_other_section
            name 'section name'
            other_section_attribute X
            ref_to_section another_section
        #end some_other_section

        #start another_section
            degrees
            #start section_i_do_not_care_about_at_the_moment
                ref_to some_other_section
                /* of course can have comments */
            #end section_i_do_not_care_about_at_the_moment
        #end another_section

    #end SECTION
#end PROJECT
```

For this i had to expand your original suggestion. I hard coded the two outer blocks (PROJECT and SECTION) because they MUST exist.

With this version the time is still at ~16s:

```
def test_parse(f):
       import pyparsing as pp
       import io
       comment = pp.cStyleComment

       start = pp.Literal("#start")
       end = pp.Literal("#end")
       ident = pp.Word(pp.alphas + "_", pp.printables)

       inner_ident = ident.copy()
       inner_start = start + inner_ident
       inner_end = end + pp.matchPreviousLiteral(inner_ident)
       inner_block = pp.Group(inner_start + pp.SkipTo(inner_end) + inner_end)

       version = pp.Literal('VERSION') - pp.Word(pp.nums)('major_version') - pp.Word(pp.nums)('minor_version')

       project = pp.Keyword('#start') - pp.Keyword('PROJECT') - pp.Word(pp.alphas + "_", pp.printables)(
              'project_name') - pp.dblQuotedString + pp.ZeroOrMore(comment) - \
                 pp.Keyword('#start') - pp.Keyword('SECTION') - pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.printables)(
              'section_name') - pp.dblQuotedString + pp.ZeroOrMore(comment) - \
                 pp.OneOrMore(inner_block) + \
                 pp.Keyword('#end') - pp.Keyword('SECTION') + \
                 pp.ZeroOrMore(comment) - pp.Keyword('#end') - pp.Keyword('PROJECT')

       grammar = pp.ZeroOrMore(comment) - version.ignore(comment) - project.ignore(comment)

       with io.open(f) as ff:
              return grammar.parseString(ff.read())
```

EDIT: Typo, said it was 2k but it instead it is a 2.7MB file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this code as posted doesn't work for me:

```
blocks = Keyword('#start') + block
```

Changing to this:

```
blocks = Keyword('#start') + MatchFirst(block)
```

at least runs against your sample text.

Rather than hard-code all the keywords, you can try using one of pyparsing's adaptive expressions, `matchPreviousLiteral`:

**(EDITED)**

```
def grammar():
    import pyparsing as pp
    comment = pp.cStyleComment

    start = pp.Keyword("#start")
    end = pp.Keyword('#end')
    ident = pp.Word(pp.alphas + "_", pp.printables)
    integer = pp.Word(pp.nums)

    inner_ident = ident.copy()
    inner_start = start + inner_ident
    inner_end = end + pp.matchPreviousLiteral(inner_ident)
    inner_block = pp.Group(inner_start + pp.SkipTo(inner_end) + inner_end)

    VERSION, PROJECT, SECTION = map(pp.Keyword, "VERSION PROJECT SECTION".split())

    version = VERSION - pp.Group(integer('major_version') + integer('minor_version'))

    project = (start - PROJECT + ident('project_name') + pp.dblQuotedString
               + start + SECTION + ident('section_name') + pp.dblQuotedString
               + pp.OneOrMore(inner_block)('blocks')
               + end + SECTION
               + end + PROJECT)

    grammar = version + project
    grammar.ignore(comment)

    return grammar
```

It is only necessary to call `ignore()` on the topmost expression in your grammar - it will propagate down to all internal expressions. Also, it should be unnecessary to sprinkle `ZeroOrMore(comment)`s in your grammar, if you have already called `ignore()`.

I parsed a 2MB input string (containing 10,000 inner blocks) in about 16 seconds, so a 2K file should only take about 1/1000th as long.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on `matchPreviousLiteral`. It is not documented in http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/HowToUsePyparsing as are some other functions. Is there any more up to date documentation?

Comment: I keep the online docs current with each release, at https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/ .  John Shipman's page at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/web/index.html is also helpful, although a bit opinionated.  See my edits above for some cleanup recommendations on your grammar.

Comment: The file size I stated at the beginning was off by 1000. It was 2.7MB from the start not 2kB. Sorry about that. I guess I won't be able to use pyparsing in this project then altough the result would be more useful, but the time difference is too much.